# C#: Decimal -> Largest integer that can be stored exactly

Tags: c#, .net

I've been looking at the decimal type for some possible programming fun in the near future, and would like to use it a a bigger integer than an Int64. One key point is that I need to find out the largest integer that I can store safely into the decimal (without losing precision); I say this, because apparently it uses some floating point in there, and as programmers, we all know the love that only floating point can give us.

So, does anyone know the largest int I can shove in there?

And on a separate note, does anyone have any experience playing with arrays of longs / ints? It's for the project following this one.

Thanks,
-R

Comment: Like [`Decimal.MaxValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.maxvalue.aspx)?

Comment: Could not make out what you are trying to ask. Have you started anything so far? Can we see something that you have done for this? Can the English be better and comprehensive?

Comment: @Kangkan: The question is written fairly clearly.

Comment: I had the phrase the question as such, as an earlier post (from another user) asked something similar when dealing with doubles, and it took several posts for him to clarify things. At any rate, Fredrik and Jon both understood the question correctly, and replied with applicable answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`decimal` works differently to `float` and `double` - it *always* has enough information to store as far as integer precision, as the maximum exponent is 28 and it has 28-29 digits of precision. You may be interested in my articles on [decimal floating point](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx) and [binary floating point](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx) on .NET to look at the differences more closely.

So you can store any integer in the range `[decimal.MinValue, decimal.MaxValue]` without losing any precision.

If you want a wider range than that, you should use [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) as Fredrik mentioned (assuming you're on .NET 4, of course... I believe there are 3rd party versions available for earlier versions of .NET).

Comment: Very good. I was reading some information regarding the breakdown of the decimal data type earlier, and became somewhat worried that I may have been missing something.

Comment: In case you didn't find the BigInteger class (like I did, initially), you need to add reference to [System.Numerics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to deal with big integers, you might want to look into the [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) type.

From the documentation:

> Represents an arbitrarily large signed integer